# Django: Get current username in model field as default value

Tags: django

```
 # models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SiteInfo(models.Model):
    site_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    site_url = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=False, default= site_owner, )
```

How to make "site_url" default value = User.username or site_owner instance?

Comment: Can you post how you query your site_owner in User? do you do it that way `user = User.Objects.filter(is_superuser=True).first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, I don't know exactly how to set a default value the way you want to, but you can override the save method, it does the same thing

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SiteInfo(models.Model):
    site_owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    site_url = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.url = self.user.username
    super(SiteInfo,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `pre_save` signal handler.

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_save, sender=SiteInfo)
def default_site_url(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if not instance.site_url:
         instance.site_url = instance.site_owner.username
```

You would need to set `blank=True` on the `site_url` model attribute otherwise form validation would never allow a blank `site_url` to be added in the first place.